# cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1

I am doing the installation on m1 mac and I am stuck mysql issue.

my rails server is working fine but when I run my spec then I got   `cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2`
error

can someone help me here?

`rspec spec/`

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
# ./config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00003 seconds (files took 5.21 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: Did you run the migration script(s) for rspec?

Comment: @gabriella-varga yes, i don't have any pending migrations

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle update mysql2`?

Comment: @gabriella-varga nothing happened. Bundler attempted to update mysql2 but its version stayed the same

Comment: @SajjadMurtaza Found any solution?, I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: @coderVishal i delete my tmp folder and it's worked for me but I am not pretty sure about the issue and solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted my `tmp/` folder and it's worked for me.

Comment: How did you delete `tmp/` folder? Some utility?